# Is it possible to break an "each" iteration, append or add something to one of the values and then continue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, nested

Is it possible to break an "each" iteration, append or add something to one of the values and then continue?

```
var aKeys = new Array(),
    aValues = new Array(),
    sArray = {};   

 $(input).each(function (index, element) {
            var sKey = $(this).attr('name'),
                sValue = $(this).val();
            aKeys.push(sKey);
            aValues.push(sValue);
        });
```

As you can see, I'm first creating a few arrays and an empty object named "sArray". Then I'm pushing the values inside those arrays via input attributes. Finally, I'm creating my object:

```
    aKeys.forEach(function (v, j) {
        sArray[v] = aValues[j];
    });

    return sArray;
```

But here's the thing. I want to add a nested object inside one of those values. I already have that object stored in another variable. Is there a way to append it or add it?

EDIT:

I've been looking at the examples and maybe I didn't express myself quite well. I've already created an object. What I wanna do is to append or store another object inside one of the keys of this object I've created.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: This is totally unclear!

Comment: `$(input).toArray().some()`

Answer (score 1):

sArray is an object, not an array. You don't need the arrays ata ll to build the object. Try this...

```js
var sObj = {};

$("input").each(function (index, element) {
  sObj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});

// Let's nest another object in there i guess...
var myObj = {"wut-wut": "in the butt"};
sObj.pickles = myObj;

console.log(sObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name=one value=1>
<input name=two value=2>
<input name=three value=3>
<input name=four value=4>
```

Comment: I know, that's what I said: "As you can see, I'm first creating a few arrays and an empty object named "sArray". The problem's not building the object, but nesting another object inside of the keys of this object I've created.

Comment: Right, but you still called it an array. What is the problem you're having with nesting? That part is not shown in your example? If you want to add an object then do it, what is stopping you?

Comment: That I want to add it to an object that it's being iterated. I need to stop the iteration, add the object to an specific key, and then continue.

Comment: @AndrewSunset - why do you need to "stop iteration?" the loop is synchronous. It automatically "stops" until the code inside it is finished then automatically continues looping.

Comment: Is that really a question? Why do I need to stop it? I already said why, and also, just because. 

Let's make it clearer: is there a way to stop and continue a forEach iteration like there is a "break" and "continue" for the "for" loops?

Comment: @AndrewSunset - the answer is no. you cannot temporarily "Stop" a forEach or a loop - and no you have not explained why. what you say you're trying to do does not require the loop to be "stopped." if you explained it better or told us what you're really trying to do then maybe i could help you better.

Comment: are you trying to do ajax inside the loop or something else that's asynchronous? because i can definitely show you how to do that.

Comment: I'll quote myself: "I need to stop the iteration, add the object to an specific key, and then continue".

Basically, add an already created object as a key's value.